# Querying posts from wordpress with 2 or more conditionals

Tags: php, wp-query

I am running a wordpress site with the Essential Grid plugin to display links to posts that I create.  The posts are events that take place over an amount of time (days/weeks/months).  I have created some custom meta fields for "eg-startdate" and "eg-enddate" and I now need to tell the grid that I only want to display posts where:

eg-startdate <= today
AND
eg-enddate >= today

I have been able to filter the grid to only show events where eg-enddate >= today using the following code:

```
function eg_mod_query($query, $grid_id){

if($grid_id == 9) {

    $query['meta_query'] = array(
    'key'     => 'eg-enddate',
    'value'   => date("d/m/Y"),
    'compare' => '>',
    'type'    => 'numeric'
    );
    $query['meta_key'] = 'eg-enddate';
    $query['meta_value'] = date("d/m/Y");
    $query['meta_value_num'] = date("d/m/Y");
    $query['meta_compare'] = '>';

}

return $query;

}
```

How do I now modify this code, so that as well as limiting posts where 'eg-enddate' is in the future, it also filters posts where 'eg-startdate' is in the past-or-today, whilst ensuring that all data is ultimately stored within $query?

Appreciate any help, thank you!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass array with multiple queries to `meta_query`.

Something like:

```
'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'eg-enddate',
            'value'   => date("d/m/Y"),
            'compare' => '>',
            'type'    => 'numeric'
        ),
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => 'eg-startdate',
            'value'   => date("d/m/Y"),
            'compare' => '<',
            'type'    => 'numeric'
        )
    )
```

For more please go through documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

Note: Code is not tried or tested so look out for syntax errors.

Comment: Thank you!! It's so simple when you see the answer, unfortunately, multi-dimensional associative arrays and I don't seem to get along too well! Really appreciate the fast response and perfect answer! +1